# Basis transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying the paper "The Degrees of Freedom of Partial Least Squares Regression" by Nicole Krämer and Masashi Sugiyama. At some point the authors use a notation which I am not familiar with.

Specifically, let $t_1,...,t_m$ be $m$ real vectors of dimension $(n \times 1)$ (these vectors are partial least squares factors, but I don't think this is important for my question) and consider also the following $m$ vectors of dimension $(n \times 1)$, $K y,K^2 y,...,K^m y$, with $K = XX' \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $X$ being a $(n \times p)$ matrix (with $p \geq m$) and $y$ an $(n \times 1)$ vector (again, I don't think knowing what exactly are $X$ and $y$ is necessary for answering my question).

According to the authors, it can be shown that $\text{span}\{t_1,...,t_m\} = \text{span}\{K y,K^2 y,...,K^m y\}$. Now, after stating this, the authors define $B = (\langle t_i,K^j y \rangle) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. They refer to $B$ is the "basis transformation". What is $B$ exactly (I have never seen this notation before)? I.e. how would one write it in "standard" matrix notation? My best guess is something like something like $B = C T^{-1}$ where $T = (t_1,...,t_m)$ and $C = (K y,K^2 y,...,K^m y)$, but I am not sure at all.

Thanks in advance and all the best.

Esben

Comment: You have written $(n \times p)$ matrix (with $p\geq m$). What is $m$ here? I suppose you mean $p\geq n$

Comment: $m$ is the number of partial least squares factors. This number cannot be larger than the number, $p$, of regressors in $X$. $n$ refers to the sample size.

Comment: For practical purposes, think of $m << p$. Like e.g. $p = 100$ and $m = 3$. There are no constraints on the relative sizes of $p$ and $n$.

Comment: By the way, by construction $t_1,...,t_m$ are linearly independent. And the same goes for $Ky,...,K^{m} y$. I.e. both T and C are invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product with respect to the standard basis in $\mathbb R^m$. Then we have
$$
\langle t_i,K^ju\rangle=\langle Te_i,Ce_j\rangle=\langle e_i,T^T Ce_j\rangle,
$$
where $T^T$ denotes the transpose of $T$. Thus,
$$
B_{ij}=\langle t_i,K^ju\rangle=\langle e_i,T^T C e_j\rangle
$$
is the matrix of $T^TC$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^m$.

Comment: This seems like a very qualified guess, I think. So, in this case the inner product is simply the dot product, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely so.